# Can you start a sentence with including?

Tags: word-usage

Including, skills such as, ball control, forehand/backhand drive, forehand/backhand lob, and strategy.

Comment: Are you writing a dodgeball manual?

Comment: That's not a sentence.

Comment: Including disadvantaged people in you social circles is an excellent way to learn compassion.

Answer (score 3):

You can:  ***Including him would be a huge mistake***.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sentence fragment and should be separated from the previous sentence using a comma or, possibly (very much case-dependent) a semicolon.  The following list should also be separated from the clause using a colon, and I'd watch your comma usage.  Something like this (assuming this is... tennis?):

*The player may find themselves in need of many skills, including: ball control, forehand/backhand drive, forehand/backhand lob, and strategy.*